# How to run a method in parallel using Julia?

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I was reading Parallel Computing docs of Julia, and having never done any parallel coding, I was left wanting a gentler intro. So, I thought of a (probably) simple problem that I couldn't figure out how to code in parallel Julia paradigm.

Let's say I have a matrix/dataframe `df` from some experiment. Its `N` rows are variables, and `M` columns are samples. I have a method `pwCorr(..)` that calculates pairwise correlation of rows. If I wanted an NxN matrix of all the pairwise correlations, I'd probably run a for-loop that'd iterate for `N*N/2` (upper or lower triangle of the matrix) and fill in the values; however, this seems like a perfect thing to parallelize since each of the `pwCorr()` calls are independent of others. (Am I correct in thinking this way about what can be parallelized, and what cannot?)

To do this, I feel like I'd have to create a `DArray` that gets filled by a `@parallel` for loop. And if so, I'm not sure how this can be achieved in Julia. If that's not the right approach, I guess I don't even know where to begin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work, first you need to [propagate the top level variable](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/julia-users/variable$20distributed/julia-users/RsX64KwJUBU/EPWOASYCMp0J) (data) to all the workers:

```
 for pid in workers()
       remotecall(pid, x->(global data; data=x; nothing), data)
       end
```

then perform the computation in chunks using the DArray constructor with some fancy indexing:

```
corrs = DArray((20,20)) do I
         out=zeros(length(I[1]),length(I[2]))
         for i=I[1], j=I[2]
           if i<j 
             out[i-minimum(I[1])+1,j-minimum(I[2])+1]= 0.0
           else
             out[i-minimum(I[1])+1,j-minimum(I[2])+1] = cor(vec(data[i,:]), vec(data[j,:]))
           end
         end
         out 
       end
```

In more detail, the `DArray` constructor takes a function which takes a tuple of index ranges and returns a chunk of the resulting matrix which corresponds to those index ranges. In the code above, `I` is the tuple of ranges with `I[1]` being the first range. You can see this more clearly with:

```
julia> DArray((10,10)) do I
       println(I)
       return zeros(length(I[1]),length(I[2]))
       end
        From worker 2:  (1:10,1:5)
        From worker 3:  (1:10,6:10)
```

where you can see it split the array into two chunks on the second axis.

The trickiest part of the example was converting from these 'global' index ranges to local index ranges by subtracting off the minimum element and then adding back 1 for the 1 based indexing of Julia.
Hope that helps!

Comment: If you want to make this answer really pop you should expand it a bit and explain what each step is doing. Expand a bit on what you mean by fancy indexing.

Comment: Ah, this looks good. Comments definitely would've helped, but I'll take something over nothing! I'm going to have to run this line by line to figure out what is going on here. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, real life sometimes takes priority, and once again I'm checking this right before bed. Maybe I'll find some time tomorrow to flesh things out a bit.

Comment: Okay, hopefully that adds some more pop!

Comment: @JKnight I think I get it. A bit more practice is needed on my part. Thanks for this!